# Map 2 arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, mithril.js

I'm trying to display the content of 2 arrays of contained in an object.
When I map RType.information.Type the content of the array "Type" is displayed.
But nothing happened if I want to display both (Type[] & Price[]).
I tried many things but nothing works..
If someone is able to help lemme know!

**JS CODE**

```
 RType.information.Type.map(function (type) {
    RType.information.Price.map(function (price) {
    return m(
        m('td.item-name', m('h4', `CLASS: ${type}`)),
        m('td.item-name', m('h4', `PRICE: ${price}`)),
        ),
      )},
   )},
```

**OBJECT**

```
var RType = {
   information : {
      Type : ["value1", "value2"],
      Price : ["112", "200"],
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking for something like this:

```js
var RType = {
   information : {
      Type : ["value1", "value2"],
      Price : ["112", "200"],
   }};
   
RType.information.Type.map((e, i) => console.log('type: ' + e + ', price: '+ RType.information.Price[i]));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I tried to do! Thank you very much!